# Find and cut out a python substring

Tags: python, string, find, substring, cut

Here is what I'm trying to do:

I have a long string:

```
s = asdf23rlkasdfidsiwanttocutthisoutsadlkljasdfhvaildufhblkajsdhf
```

I want to cut out the substring: iwanttocutthisout

I will be iterating through a loop and with each iteration the value of s will change.  The only thing that will stay the same with each iteration is the begining and end of the substring to be cut out: iwant and thisout.

How can I cut out the substring, given these parameters?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: is this the static string or you're looking for a generic solution?

Comment: Generic Solution, the length of the string can change, as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a slice between the index of occurance of `iwant` (`+len(iwant)` to dis-include `iwant`) and `thisout` respectively, like so:

```
>>> s = "asdf23rlkasdfidsiwanttocutthisoutsadlkljasdfhvaildufhblkajsdhf"
>>> s[s.index("iwant")+len("iwant"):s.index("thisout")]
'tocut'
```

Diagramatically:

```
"asdf23rlkasdfids(iwanttocut)thisoutsadlkljasdfhvaildufhblkajsdhf"
                 ^          ^ 
                 |          |
            index("iwant")  |
                           index("thisout")
```

Notice how slicing between these two indexes (beginning inclusive) would get `iwanttocut`. Adding `len("iwant")` would result in:

```
"asdf23rlkasdfidsiwant(tocut)thisoutsadlkljasdfhvaildufhblkajsdhf"
                      ^     ^ 
                 /----|     |
     index("iwant")         |
                           index("thisout")
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `sub()` function in the `re` module like this:

`clean_s = re.sub(r'iwant\w+thisout','',s)`

Substitute \w+ for .+ if you're expecting non-word characters in your string and use * instead of + if there is a chance that there won't be any extra characters between the start and end tags (i.e. 'iwantthisout')

Answer (score 1):

```
s = s.replace('iwantthisout', '')
```