# python3.6 How do I regex a url from a .txt?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to grab a url from a text file.

The URL is stored in a string like so: `'URL=http://example.net'`.

Is there anyway I could grab everything after the `=` char up until the `.` in `'.net'`?

Could I use the `re` module?

Comment: `url = url[4:url.rfind('.')]`?

Comment: Hey, what do you know. That worked. Thanks for the help my friend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
text = """A key feature of effective analytics infrastructure in healthcare is a metadata-driven architecture. In this article, three best practice scenarios are discussed: https://www.healthcatalyst.com/clinical-applications-of-machine-learning-in-healthcare Automating ETL processes so data analysts have more time to listen and help end users , https://www.google.com/, https://www.facebook.com/, https://twitter.com
code below catches all urls in text and returns urls in list."""
```

`urls = re.findall('(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?[\w/\-?=%.]+\.[\w/\-?=%.]+', text)`

`print(urls)`

output:

```
[ 
   'https://www.healthcatalyst.com/clinical-applications-of-machine-learning-in-healthcare',
   'https://www.google.com/',
   'https://www.facebook.com/',
   'https://twitter.com'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont have much information but i will try to help with what i got im assuming that URL= is part of the string in that case you can do this

```
re.findall(r'URL=(.*?).', STRINGNAMEHERE)
```

Let me go more into detail about (.*?) the dot means Any character (except newline character) the star means zero or more occurences and the ? is hard to explain but heres an example from the docs "Causes the resulting RE to match 0 or 1 repetitions of the preceding RE. ab? will match either ‘a’ or ‘ab’." the brackets place it all into a group. All this togethear basicallly means it will find everything inbettween URL= and .

Comment: Hm. Seems to be pulling an empty list... I would print this instead of, for example, using group() like when using re.search(), yes?

Comment: do you have newline charachters in your string

Answer (score 0):

You don't need RegEx'es (the `re` module) for such a simple task.

If the string you have is of the form:
`'URL=http://example.net'`

Then you can solve this using basic Python in numerous ways, one of them being:

```
file_line = 'URL=http://example.net'
start_position = file_line.find('=') + 1  # this gives you the first position after =
end_position = file_line.find('.')

# this extracts from the start_position up to but not including end_position
url = file_line[start_position:end_position]
```

Of course that this is just going to extract one URL. Assuming that you're working with a large text, where you'd want to extract all URLs, you'll want to put this logic into a `function` so that you can reuse it, and build around it (achieve iteration via the `while` or `for` loops, and, depending on how you're iterating, keep track of the position of the last extracted URL and so on).

---

### Word of advice

This question has been answered quite a lot on this forum, by very skilled people, in numerous ways, for instance: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572362/get-a-string-after-a-specific-substring), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17567731/find-and-cut-out-a-python-substring), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48959833/how-to-split-string-after-certain-character-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46766530/python-split-a-string-by-the-position-of-a-character), to a level of detail that you'd be amazed. And these are not all, I just picked the first few that popped up in my search results.

Given that (at the time of posting this question) you're a new contributor to this site, my friendly advice would be to invest some effort into finding such answers. It's a crucial skill, that you can't do without in the world of programming.

Remember, that whatever problem it is that you are encountering, there is a **very high chance** that somebody on this forum had already encountered it, and received an answer, you just need to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. It worked for me.

```
import re
s='url=http://example.net'
print(re.findall(r"=(.*)\.",s)[0])
```